# How to Parse an HTML STYLE Attribute with Regex?

Tags: .net, regex

What is the proper Regex construction (.NET flavor) to extract the attribute/value pairs from an HTML style string, *while ignoring HTML entities*?

```
margin-top:0pt;margin:0;color:#000000;margin-left:0;font-size:26pt;margin-bottom:3pt;line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left;margin-right:0
```

Splitting on `;` and then on `:` would be simplest but as HTML Entities contain semicolons, this breaks on some strings.  For example, entities can exist in the `font-family` style attribute.

```
font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;;
```

The style string is isolated (no `style="`), and single-line.

Ultimately I'll be regex-grouping them in this arrangement;

```
match:( 
    group:( style-attribute-name ) 
    group:( style-attribute-value ) 
    )
```

Iterating through the groups to create a dictionary (with duplicate keys getting replaced).

My current Regex looks like this-

```
\s*(?<attr>[^:\s]*)\s*:\s*(?<val>[^;]*)[;]\s*
```

And results in mis-matches when it hits the HTML entities.

[image]

Comment: @ThomasMoors He does not want to parse HTML here... Just a list of attributes. Don't link this comment every single time "HTML" and "regex" are in the same sentence.

Comment: As far as I know, all HTML entities begin with `&` and end with `;`, am I wrong ? We could use that.

Comment: Thanks @Gawil - correct, however the style string delimiter is also `;`.  I'm pretty familiar with doing basic regex, but I'm sure how to define a sort of sub-pattern that ignores entities and handles them as style-value content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your regex, using balancing groups to skip `;` when it is preceded by `&`.
Here is the regex :
`(?<attr>[^:\s]*)\s*:\s*(?<val>(?:[^;&]*(?<html>&)?[^;&]*(?(html);(?<-html>)))+)(?:;|$)`
Demo [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3cattr%3e%5b%5e%3a%5cs%5d*%29%5cs*%3a%5cs*%28%3f%3cval%3e%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%3b%26%5d*%28%3f%3chtml%3e%26%29%3f%5b%5e%3b%26%5d*%28%3f%28html%29%3b%28%3f%3c-html%3e%29%29%29%2b%29%28%3f%3a%3b%7c%24%29&i=margin-top%3a0pt%3bmargin%3a0%3bcolor%3a%23000000%3bmargin-left%3a0%3bfont-size%3a26pt%3bmargin-bottom%3a3pt%3bline-height%3a1.15%3bpage-break-after%3aavoid%3bfont-family%3a%26quot%3bArial%26quot%3b%3borphans%3a2%3bwidows%3a2%3btext-align%3aleft%3bmargin-right%3a0)

*Note : I have mostly replaced* `[^;]*` *by* `(?:[^;&]*(?<html>&)?[^;&]*(?(html);(?<-html>)))+` *in the groupe* `val` *from your regex.*

Comment: Exactly what I needed- I don't think I have seen a balancing group construction before.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Memetican A pleasure ! Yeah balancing group is a feature specific to .NET flavour. It can be seen like a stack. Read this if you're interested, it's very helpful : http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.regextester.com
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet

These helped me when I was screwing around with regex in school, not near my computer rn so I can't easily write it for ya :/

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks Dom, good stuff.  I've built a good regex tester that lets me beat up the .NET variant quite well.  The part I don't know is how to get it to identify HTML entities, and simply absorb them into the VAL group without getting killed by the semicolon.